# babelify transformation on JSX for React element failing

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I am new to React.js and trying out some examples.
I have the following code in my js file:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var header = <h1>Test</h1>   
ReactDOM.render(header, document.getElementById('react-application'));
```

My index.html file has the div with the id `react-application`.

The contents of the gulpfile are:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', function(){
       return browserify('./source/app.js')
            .transform(babelify)
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('test.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
      });
```

When I run 'gulp', I am getting the following error:

```
e:/react/test/source/app.js: Unexpected token (4:13)
[0m  2 | [36mvar[39m ReactDOM [1m=[22m require[94m[1m([22m[39m[31m'react-dom'[39m[94m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m
  3 |
> 4 | [36mvar[39m header [1m=[22m [1m<[22mh1[1m>[22mTest[1m<[22m[1m/[22mh1[1m>[22m
    |              ^
  5 |
  6 | ReactDOM[1m.[22mrender[94m[1m([22m[39mheader[1m,[22m document[1m.[22mgetElementById[94m[1m([22m[39m[31m'react-application'[39m[94m[1m)[22m[39m[94m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m[0m......
```

The same code renders correctly on [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/repl/).
The error is on the line where the html is assigned to the var header.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the babel version you are using?

Starting from Babel 6 you need to declare the presets manually, check [this](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/).

Basically, in the root of your project you need a `.babelrc` with the following content:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

And the corresponding npm modules in package.json:

```
// package.json

{
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I am using babelify 7.2.0. I later included both the preset packages, but had missed the .babelrc file.